# Как узнать установлен ли WhatsApp?

Tags: java, android

Как узнать установлен ли на телефоне WhatsApp не вызывая startActivity?

Comment: Теги намекают, что Вы неправильно обзываете это приложение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте этот вариант:

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (launchIntent == null) { 
    //значит приложения нет
}
```